# How do i convert python list into pandas dataframe with predefined columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have python string list, which i want to convert into pandas dataframe with predefined columns. I have tried following code but it shows error.

I have tried following code.

```
  import pandas as pd
  list = ['jack', '9860', 'datasc', 'vill','0', 'stack']
  df = pd.DataFrame(list, columns= ['name', 'no','job'])
```

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 6), indices imply (3, 6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use variable `list`, because python code word (builtin).

Convert `list` to numpy array and [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
L = ['jack', '9860', 'datasc', 'vill','0', 'stack']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(L).reshape(-1,3), columns= ['name', 'no','job'])
print (df)
   name    no     job
0  jack  9860  datasc
1  vill     0   stack
```

Comment: what is mean reshape(-1,3)

Comment: @Coder - `-1` means count number of `N` in shape - (Nx3) - it means it create `3 columns` and counted number of rows by number of values in list.

Comment: @Coder - similar solution in last paragraph in [example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)